# Ways to retain a focus ring on a transparent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm in the process of building an input in a form that contains a profile picture that, when clicked, will allow a user to select a new image. It looks like the common practice is to use an input with the type of "file" and then hide it through various means. Setting `opacity:0` seems to be the only legitimate option to me, as this will keep the element in the DOM and it will still detect clicks or focus.

However, an input with no opacity will also not have a visible focus ring, even though the element is technically in focus. What are the options I have at my disposal in order to have a focus ring show when focused? Thank you in advance.

```css
.profile-pic {
  width: 156px;
  height: 156px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.profile-pic input[type='file'] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.profile-pic__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.profile-pic__img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.65);
  transition: filter 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.profile-pic__img img:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.5);
}

.profile-pic__text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
}

.profile-pic__text .fa-camera {
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-pic span {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-pic">
  <input type="file" />
  <div class="profile-pic__img">
    <img src="[TEST_URL]" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile-pic__text">
    <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
    <span>Click to change photo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply [the `:focus-within` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) to the `.profile-pic` and give it distinctive styling when the transparent input has the focus.

```css
.profile-pic {
  width: 156px;
  height: 156px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.profile-pic:focus-within {
    outline: dotted #777 2px;
}

.profile-pic input[type='file'] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.profile-pic__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.profile-pic__img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.65);
  transition: filter 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.profile-pic__img img:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.5);
}

.profile-pic__text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
}

.profile-pic__text .fa-camera {
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-pic span {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-pic">
  <input type="file" />
  <div class="profile-pic__img">
    <img src="[TEST_URL]" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile-pic__text">
    <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
    <span>Click to change photo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need an invisible element to have a focus ring, if it's invisible.

You could add a focus ring to your `.profile-pic` element instead, because it's actually visible and visually interactive.

You can make your `.profile-pic` element focusable by adding a `tabindex="0"` attribute to it. Then just select it in CSS via `.profile-pic:focus` and design a focus ring.

I know I haven't really answered your question, but I hope this helps.

Comment: That's probably going to introduce some usability problems. I don't know if pressing the activation key would trigger the input when the focus in on a `tabindex` ancestor, and its very likely to give an unhelpful (i.e. not "this is a file input") announcement when a screen reader hits the `tabindex` element.

Comment: That's right. You could nest the input into the `label`, thus pressing the insides of the label would trigger the `input`. Or trigger the `input` via JS, and attach to your `div` attributes like `role="button" aria-label="Upload file"`, while `input` is going to be `display: none;` and going to have `aria-hidden="true";`

But maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Actually @Quentin, your solution is awesome

Comment: I had high hopes for the tabindex solution, but this allows the parent div to be in focus, such that when the user hits enter nothing happens. I suppose this could be solved through some javascript however.

Answer (score -1):

Basically the same answer as [Quentin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77195306/215552), except I wanted to keep the pseudo-class applied to the `input`, so I used a `box-shadow` rather than a `outline`. Six of one, half-dozen of another.

```css
.profile-pic {
  width: 156px;
  height: 156px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.profile-pic input[type='file'] {
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.profile-pic input[type='file']:focus-within {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 5px blue;
}

.profile-pic__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.profile-pic__img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.65);
  transition: filter 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.profile-pic__img img:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.5);
}

.profile-pic__text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
}

.profile-pic__text .fa-camera {
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-pic span {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-pic">
  <input type="file" />
  <div class="profile-pic__img">
    <img src="[TEST_URL]" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile-pic__text">
    <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
    <span>Click to change photo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```